# Persistence unit as RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence, jta

I have queries as below:

1. What is the difference of these two?
2. Are both of these supported by all databases?
3. Are JPA TransactionManager and JTA TransactionManager different?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

JPA implementations have the choice of managing transactions themselves (`RESOURCE_LOCAL`), or having them managed by the application server's JTA implementation.

In most cases, RESOURCE_LOCAL is fine. This would use basic JDBC-level transactions. The downside is that the transaction is local to the JPA persistence unit, so if you want a transaction that spans multiple persistence units (or other databases), then RESOURCE_LOCAL may not be good enough.

JTA is also used for managing transactions across systems like JMS and JCA, but that's fairly exotic usage for most of us.

To use JTA, you need support for it in your application server, and also support from the JDBC driver.

Comment: it seems glassfih does not allow me t use resource_local - how can I do that?

Comment: _As a side note:_  one still can get JTA functionality, even without a full Java EE application server by using third party solutions, like for example [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/). So you can have a lightweight web container like Tomcat and still get the JTA support.

Answer (score 100):

*As an addition to other answers*

Here is an **excerpt** from the extremely useful article (published on the [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/index.html) website), which can also help answer the OP's first question (the link to the article is below).

---

> #### Comparing RESOURCE_LOCAL and JTA persistence
>   contexts
>
> ---
>
> With *<persistence-unit
>   transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">*
>   **YOU** are responsible for EntityManager
>   (PersistenceContext/Cache) creating and tracking...
>
> - You **must** use the
>     **EntityManagerFactory** to get an EntityManager
> - The resulting **EntityManager** instance
>     **is** a PersistenceContext/Cache
> - An
>     **EntityManagerFactory** can be injected via the
>     **@PersistenceUnit** annotation only (not
>     @PersistenceContext)
> - You are **not** allowed to
>     use @PersistenceContext to refer to a unit of type RESOURCE_LOCAL
> - You **must** use the
>     **EntityTransaction** API to begin/commit around
>     **every** call to your EntityManger
> - Calling
>     entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() twice results in
>     **two** separate EntityManager instances and therefor
>     **two** separate PersistenceContexts/Caches.
> - It
>     is **almost never** a good idea to have more than one
>     **instance** of an EntityManager in use (don't create a
>     second one unless you've destroyed the first)
>
> With *<persistence-unit
>   transaction-type="JTA">* the
>   **CONTAINER** will do EntityManager
>   (PersistenceContext/Cache) creating and tracking...
>
> - You **cannot** use the
>     **EntityManagerFactory** to get an EntityManager
> - You can only get an **EntityManager** supplied by the
>     **container**
> - An **EntityManager**
>     can be injected via the **@PersistenceContext**
>     annotation only (not @PersistenceUnit)
> - You are
>     **not** allowed to use @PersistenceUnit to refer to a
>     unit of type JTA
> - The **EntityManager** given by
>     the container is a **reference** to the
>     PersistenceContext/Cache associated with a JTA Transaction.
> - If no JTA transaction is in progress, the EntityManager
>     **cannot be used** because there is no
>     PersistenceContext/Cache.
> - Everyone with an EntityManager
>     reference to the **same unit** in the **same
>     transaction** will automatically have a reference to the
>     **same PersistenceContext/Cache**
> - The
>     PersistenceContext/Cache is **flushed** and cleared at
>     JTA **commit** time

---

Anyone interested in learning the Java Persistence API - please do yourself a favor and read the full article here: [JPA Concepts: JPA 101](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html).

Comment: Just wanted to add one point: If you are using Spring you can use @ PersistenceContext and EntityManager with Resource_Local. In this case the Spring container can manage the transaction using @ Transactional annotation.

Comment: In my project `transaction-type=RESOURCE_LOCAL` and `@PersistenceContext` and `@Transactional` managed by Spring

Comment: I am hitting the triangle facing up because of the link you provided.

Comment: @KorayTugay I am sorry, didn't quite understand what you say, what triangle?

Comment: @informatik01 upvote button. (i can not just comment plus 1, not allowed!)

Comment: @KorayTugay Oh, it's OK. Hope you found useful information here )

Comment: @informatik01 Ok... I think there are common rules with JTA and I want to clarify on think. Is correct that **flush** is sending data to DB if is triggered? In my case I trigger **flush** some changes are propagated to DB and also exception is occurring; after I trigger **rollback** (using setRollbackOnly) but the propagated changes are still in DB.

Comment: @LinuRadu This answer might be helpful for you: [What's the use of session.flush() in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322619/814702)

Comment: @informatik01 Thanks. Is very interesting because on my flush action the changes are sent to DB and could ne be reverted

Answer (score 19):

Resource_Local and JTA are transaction managers (methods of doing transactions). This is not the property of database but the component responsible for coordinating transactions. JPA and JTA transaction managers are different. JPA transaction manager is responsible for JPA transactions and you want to use one if you are only doing JPA transaction. JTA transaction manager is general purpose transaction manager and can enlist other resources such as JMS queues in transaction. Typically Java EE containers employ a JTA transaction manager for EJBs, JPA entities, etc.

Answer (score 1):

resource_local vs JTA its about local transaction vs global transaction. It's about can we manage multiple resources under a single transaction.

CMT vs BMT its about who is opening and closing transaction - application developer or application server.