# Spring Transactional annotation, isolation not working for READ_UNCOMMITTED

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a method in Java which is wrapped by a `spring Transactional` annotation.

I have 2 operations inside, one is `delete`, another one is `insert`. My insertion statement have to rely on the first operation (which is the `delete`), but now because of the first operation is not committed yet, my insertion fail (unique constraint). But this is funny that, usually within the same transaction, I should be able to read/see the uncommited operation in the same transaction (my old proprietary framework are able to do that), but this is not happening for my scenario, the second insertion still fail because it see the data is not yet deleted.

I try to use isolation `READ_UNCOMMITTED`, but it doesn't work.

I have to put these two operation in same transaction, because any of the failure should rollback both operations, I can't commit the first operation then proceed to the second one.

How can I do that in Spring framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in Hibernate , in the same transaction , `while flushing(committing) it always follows a particular order.`

`Inserts` are first executed and then `deletes` are executed while flushing.

So ideally in your case , since you are `deleting` before `insert` just call `enitityManager.flush()` explicitly after `delete` .

Alternatively also have a look at `EntityManager.setFlushMode()` method where you can set to flush mode type to either `commit` or `auto`

Comment: This flush mode really killing me, how come the default flushing is not by code order... "it always follows a particular order", is there any doc i can refer to? there should be some reason for this...

Comment: according to this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html, my config should be default as "auto", how come it doesn't flush before "all query execution"?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/def/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.EventSource%29