# Hibernate session.flush() even though autocommit is set

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, session

I realised to need to call session.flush() for entities whose primary key is not a GeneratedValue before they are persisted in the database. And I have to do this even though I have already autocommit set to true.
Here is my hibernate configuration

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${hibernate.connection.driver_class}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">${hibernate.connection.url}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">${hibernate.connection.username}</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">${hibernate.connection.password}</property>
<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

and here is an example for the entity for which i need to call session.flush() after in code after saving before it gets persisted

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MembTypeCode")
    private String memTypeCode;
    @Column(name = "MemberType")
    private String memberType;
  ...
```

but for entities whose Id is a GeneratedValue (like the one below), I do not need to call session.flush() in code after saving in order for it to get persisted in the database because i have autocommit set to true.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PrescriptId")
private int prescriptId;
@Column(name = "InvNum")
private Integer invNum;
@Column(name = "DocType")
private String docType;
...
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am experiencing this? I'm using Hibernate 4.1.0.FINAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocommit and `session.flush()` are two different things:

1. Autocommit sets the autocommit mode on the underlying JDBC transaction. It basically means that every SQL statement (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, ...) is executed in its own transaction.
2. `session.flush()` tells Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state with the database, so to write SQL statements to the JDBC connection. See more here: [What's the use of session.flush() in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220336/whats-the-use-of-session-flush-in-hibernate)

So while I do not know why entities in your example only get persisted to the database in one case, it likely has nothing to do with the autocommit mode.