# Unable to generate constraint violation exception when testing Hibernate @Check constraints

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am playing with Hibernate `@Check` annotation but **can not have my test fail when constraints are not satisfied**. Currently just using default Spring boot configuration with H2 database.

What am I missing? Should there be a some kind of a *flush* after `save(..)`?

When running test I see the table created correctly. If I copy the creation line from the log and using it create a table to my 'real' Postgres database I can test different inserts and see that this line is all fine with constraints.

**Entity**

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity @Check(constraints = "a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT NULL")
public class Constrained {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String a, b;
}
```

**Test**

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class HibernateCheckTest {

    @Resource // this repo is just some boiler plate code but attached at 
              // the bottom of question
    private ConstrainedRepository repo;

    @Test @Transactional // also tried without @Transactional
    public void test() {
        Constrained c = new Constrained();
        repo.save(c); // Am I wrong to expect some constraint exception here?
    }
}
```

**Table generation script while running test**

> create table constrained (id bigint not null, a varchar(255), b
>   varchar(255), primary key (id), check (a IS NOT NULL OR b IS NOT
>   NULL))

**Repository** (not much to see in repo but just to show it):

```
public interface ConstrainedRepository
            extends CrudRepository<Constrained, Long> {
}
```

**HOWEVER**

If I use `EntityManager` so adding to my test class:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and doing the persist like:

```
em.persist(c);
em.flush();
```

instead of `repo.save(c)` I will get the exception.

**AND**

studying the log from the original test with `repo.save(c)` more careful shows:

> org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext:139 - Rolled back transaction for test:
>   ...
>   testException = [null],

so for some reason this error is just wrapped and logged. How to have it "unwrapped" and thrown when using repository for persisting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53238183/6413377) from **codemonkey** I was able to find a solution. This resolves by adding:

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = 
                                                     Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

to my test class.

Comment: exactly also solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

In `ConstrainedRepository`, extend `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` then use:

```
repo.saveAndFlush(c);
```

instead of:

```
repo.save(c);
```

The check is enforced in the database and that only happens when the changes (in this case an INSERT statement) are flushed to the database.

Without an explicit flush, [Hibernate will defer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220403/6797663) sending the statements to the database until the transaction is committed or a query is executed.

However, from the Spring [DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) documentation:

> By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end
>   of each test.

So, in this case, there is not commit. The transaction is rolled back and the statements are never flushed to the database, and therefore the exception is never thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I would have assumed something like that. I have seen this method in some Q&As but my problem now is that my repos do not contain that method? Should i construct myt repo or test somehow differently? (i'm browsing the docs also but if you know quick answer)

Comment: Ah, sorry that method is in JpaRepository but not CrudRepository. Have updated my answer.