# ConstraintViolationException thrown only when trying to find in database during test

Tags: spring-boot, validation, jpa, h2

I'm using JPA repository and H2 in memory database and everything is working fine in my application, the errors shown as expected when trying to input invalid values. Then I started to make some tests and I don't know why I'm not getting ConstraintViolationException when trying to do `repository.save`.
I have this class:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty (message = "The user name cannot be empty")
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @Email(message = "Please, insert a valid e-mail")
    @NotEmpty (message = "The user e-mail cannot be empty")
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "The user cpf cannot be empty")
    private String cpf;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @NotNull(message = "The user birthday cannot be empty")
    @Past
    private LocalDate birthDate;
}
```

and this test is passing

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("Save throws ConstraintViolationException user when user is empty")
    void save_ThrowsConstraintViolationException_WhenUserIsEmpty() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setCpf("");


        Assertions.assertThatNoException()
                .isThrownBy(() -> this.userRepository.save(user));

        Assertions.assertThatExceptionOfType(ConstraintViolationException.class)
                .isThrownBy(() -> this.userRepository.findByCpf(""));

    }
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53237507/6413377)

Answer (score 0):

In tests I always use `saveAndFlush()` because `save()` only calls EntityManager.persist() and doesn't execute any SQL statements, expect when you have have a ID with GenerationType.IDENTITY.

So try this:

```
Assertions.assertThatNoException()
            .isThrownBy(() -> this.userRepository.saveAndFlush(user));
```