# Hibernate continuously executing delete statements on the join table

Tags: hibernate

I am facing an issue with hibernate many-to-many relationship join table. I have two entities that have many to many relationship.

```
This is the Post class
------------------------
@ManyToMany(
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        }
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

This is the Tag class
----------------------
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    public Set<Post> getPost() {
        return posts;
}


This is the join table class (post_tag)
------------------------------------------
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    public Post getPost() {
        return post;
    }


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    public Tag getTag() {
        return tag;
}
```

I am seeing this query getting called almost 5K times in an hour even on GET calls. Wondering if there are any obvious mistakes in the mapping here?

```
FROM post_tag
WHERE post_id=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. The problem was with the Session.flush() method. The flush() method executes based upon flush configuration (AUTO, MANUAL, COMMIT and ALWAYS). This link helped to understand about Session.flush()

[What's the use of session.flush() in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220336/whats-the-use-of-session-flush-in-hibernate)