# What is the difference between LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, spring-orm

Can anybody explain what is the difference between the Spring Framework's *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* and *LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean*?

Answer (score 46):

Basically **JPA specification** defines ***two types of entity managers***. They are :
**i) Application-Managed :** Application Managed entity manager means "Entity Managers are created and managed by merely the application ( i.e. our code )" .

**ii) Container Managed :** Container Managed entity manager means "Entity Managers are created and managed by merely the J2EE container ( i.e. our code doesn't directly manages instead entity managers are created and managed by container , and our code gets EM's through some way like using JNDI ).

Note : Created and Managed (above) means "opening , closing and involving entity manager in transactions"

**LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean** - container managed 
**LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean** - application managed

***A Big Note :*** For spring based applications, the *difference is not much*. *Spring only plays roles* ( as **container** if you configure *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* and as **application** if you configure *LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean*)

Answer (score 18):

The documentation says it all:

[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) -- From the link: FactoryBean that creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's standard **container** bootstrap contract.

[LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) -- From the link: FactoryBean that creates a JPA EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's standard **standalone** bootstrap contract.

Essentially, the only difference is in how they create the JPA `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: I'm still confuse between the container and standalone. Any reference I can read?

Comment: @huahsin68 Maybe this answer will shead some light for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28998110/814702

Comment: What is **'JPA's standard container bootstrap contract.'**  Is there any article about that?

Answer (score 18):

LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean

is the simplest and the most limited. You cannot refer to an existing JDBC
DataSource bean definition and no support for global transactions exists.

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

is the most powerful JPA setup
option, allowing for flexible local configuration within the application. It supports links to an existing JDBC DataSource, supports both local and global transactions

REF: spring-framework-reference.pdf "Spring 3"

Answer (score 12):

LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean produces an application-managed EntityManagerFactory.

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean produces a container-managed
EntityManagerFactory.

Ref : Spring In Action - Craig Walls

Answer (score 2):

- Both implementations LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean and
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean returns EntityManagerFactory
  reference from
  org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.
- Each implementation will use resource_local transaction unless we
  explicitly ask Spring to use JTA.
- A major difference between the two implementations is
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean provide programmatically
  setting persistence unit (data source & packageToScan), is more
  flexible in that we can override the location of the persistence.xml
  file compare to LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean in which we have to use a predefined name persistence.xml

If both are using resource_local as default then it does not thumb rule that LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is using container-managed transaction and other is using application-managed transaction.

When using JPA outside of a dependency injection container, transactions need to be handled programmatically by the developer. If using JPA inside of Spring dependency injection container then it can be handled by Spring container.

Example using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

```
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        //LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lfb.setPersistenceUnitName("localEntity");
        lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        lfb.setPackagesToScan("com.javasampleapproach.h2database.model");
        lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
        return lfb;
    }
}
@Component
public class PostRepository {
  @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
  }
  public void create(){
      EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
      Post post = new Post("First post");
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.persist(post);
      em.getTransaction().commit();
  }
}
```

Error with LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create a transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead**

```
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lfb.setPersistenceUnitName("localEntity");
        lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
        return lfb;
    }
}

@Component
    public class PostRepository {
      @Autowired
      EntityManager em;

      public void create(){
          EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
          Post post = new Post("First post");
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          em.persist(post);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
      }
    }
<persistence-unit name="localEntity">
</persistence-unit>
```

Working code with LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean

**Spring managed transaction like container-managed in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.**

```
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lfb.setPersistenceUnitName("localEntity");
        lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
        return lfb;
    }
}

@Component
public class PostRepository {
  @Autowired
  EntityManagerFactory emf;

  @Transactional
  public void create() {
    Post post = new Post("First post");
    em.persist(post);
  }
}

<persistence-unit name="localEntity">
</persistence-unit>
```

Both implementations can be used under container-managed transaction, please correct me on this if some correction is need.

Comment: 1st example has a spurious } after emf.  2nd injects em, but uses inexistent emf to create another inner em.  3rd injects emf, but uses inexistent em.

Answer (score 1):

To use JPA in a Spring project, we need to set up the EntityManager.

This is the main part of the configuration, and we can do it via a Spring factory bean.
This can be either the simpler **LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean** or the more flexible **LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean**.

baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Answer (score -1):

LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean creates EntityManagerFactory via  PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory()

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean creates EntityManagerFactory via  PersistenceProvider.createContainterEntityManagerFactory()