# Migration of an Spring, Hibernate 3.6.3-JPA application to Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, migration

Hello I'm trying to migrate an Hibernate 3.6.3 application to Hibernate 4 and I'm getting following error:

```
 Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class 
 [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]: 
 Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid 
 setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the 
 return type of the getter?
```

I have looked a this post:
[integrating JPA and SpringIOc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357533/integrating-jpa-and-springioc)

When I use LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean I get the error mentioned above, but when I use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I get an error when creating my DAO bean.

I think it's a problem of spring.orm dependency configuration, but I'm not sure, since all the dependency changes I have made aren't working.

Where can I find a Hibernate 4 migration guide in order to adapt my JPA, Hibernate 3.6.3 and Spring application?

Comment: I think you may have to use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html)

> This EntityManagerFactory bootstrap is appropriate for standalone
>   applications which solely use JPA for data access. If you want to set
>   up your persistence provider for an external DataSource and/or for
>   global transactions which span multiple resources, you will need to
>   either deploy it into a full Java EE 5 application server and access
>   the deployed EntityManagerFactory via JNDI, or use Spring's
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with appropriate configuration
>   for local setup according to JPA's container contract.

Which means you may have to use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    ....
    ....
</bean>
```

Ex:

Comment: If I use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean I get: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' ... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin ... org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Comment: which is the hibernate and spring versions used

Comment: My application was using Hibernate 3.6.3 but now I have changed the hibernate-core dependency to version 4.17