# EntityManager handling

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA 2 and I want to find out which are the best practices for handling an `EntityManager` on `RESOURCE_LOCAL` and with JTA. From what I have read, I should be able to make a dependency injection, but I do not quite understand how.

I am using EclipseLink as an implementation.

Comment: Have you read this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/usclient003.htm

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? You can inject an EntityManager directly into your code but there are a few gotcha's you have to watch out for. Please edit your question to include the specific error or problem.

Comment: @Perception I am not using EJBs so I do not know how to make those injections. Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a reference to EntityManager in your bean, use the following annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Or if you are not using EJB:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnitName");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
//Do some work...
entityManager.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
```

See [Persistence unit as RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962525/persistence-unit-as-resource-local-or-jta) for an explanation of RESOURCE_LOCAL vs JTA.

Comment: I am not using EJBs. Where and how does the application find the right EntityManager?

Comment: Then you have to use javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory (answer edited)