# Why tomcat does not see the update in the database?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jpa, netbeans, h2

I am currently in netbeans I develop a web application with java. I use JPA2.0 with H2 Database.

The problem is that when I change the data in the database and I reloaded the page in the browser=>no change is set.
Only if I rerun a `jsp` page in `netbeans`, or I restart tomcat:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutAutomobile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutConducteur</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutConducteur</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutMission</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutMission</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutUtilisateur</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutUtilisateur</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectCinConducteur</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectCinConducteur</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectIdAuto</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectIdAuto</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectIdAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectIdAutomobile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutVignette</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutVignette</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectImei</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectImei</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAssurance</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutAssurance</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutVisite</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutVisite</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutIntervention</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutIntervention</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectAutoLibre</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectAutoLibre</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectConducteurLibre</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectConducteurLibre</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>afficheInfoGeo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.afficheInfoGeo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAffectation</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.ajoutAffectation</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>afficheListConducteur</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.afficheListConducteur</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>afficheInfoGeoRestreinte</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.afficheInfoGeoRestreinte</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectDate</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectDate</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectCoordsRestreinte</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectCoordsRestreinte</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectAssuranceExpir</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectAssuranceExpir</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectVignetteExpir</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectVignetteExpir</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectVisiteExpir</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectVisiteExpir</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectAssurance</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectAssurance</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectVignette</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectVignette</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selectVisite</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.selectVisite</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>afficheListAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.afficheListAutomobile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>historiqueAffectationConducteur</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.historiqueAffectationConducteur</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>historiqueAffectationAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controlleurs.historiqueAffectationAutomobile</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutAutomobile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutConducteur</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutConducteur</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutMission</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutMission</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutUtilisateur</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutUtilisateur</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectCinConducteur</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectCinConducteur</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectIdAuto</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectIdAuto</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectIdAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectIdAutomobile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutVignette</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutVignette</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectImei</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectImei</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAssurance</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutAssurance</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutVisite</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutVisite</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutIntervention</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutIntervention</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectAutoLibre</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectAutoLibre</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectConducteurLibre</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectConducteurLibre</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>afficheInfoGeo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afficheInfoGeo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ajoutAffectation</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ajoutAffectation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>afficheListConducteur</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afficheListConducteur</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>afficheInfoGeoRestreinte</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afficheInfoGeoRestreinte</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectDate</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectDate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectCoordsRestreinte</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectCoordsRestreinte</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectAssuranceExpir</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectAssuranceExpir</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectVignetteExpir</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectVignetteExpir</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectVisiteExpir</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectVisiteExpir</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectAssurance</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectAssurance</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectVignette</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectVignette</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selectVisite</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/selectVisite</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>afficheListAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/afficheListAutomobile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>historiqueAffectationConducteur</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/historiqueAffectationConducteur</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>historiqueAffectationAutomobile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/historiqueAffectationAutomobile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
           30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

How to solve this problem please ?

**EDIT**: I have tried to delete cache, also open the page in other browser =>same result..

**EDIT2**:
persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="webPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entities.Automobile</class>
    <class>entities.Intervention</class>
    <class>entities.Assurance</class>
    <class>entities.Coordonnees</class>
    <class>entities.Mission</class>
    <class>entities.Affectation</class>
    <class>entities.Conducteur</class>
    <class>entities.Gps</class>
    <class>entities.Vignette</class>
    <class>entities.Utilisateur</class>
    <class>entities.VisiteTechnique</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/ApiGps"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("webPU"); 


       Timestamp nd=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());//now
       nd.setMinutes(nd.getMinutes()-20);
      EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
      String req="select a from Automobile a where a.gpsImei.imei in (SELECT c.gpsImei.imei FROM Coordonnees c WHERE c.date < :nd )";
      Query resultat=em.createQuery(req);
      resultat.setParameter("nd", nd);
      java.util.List<Automobile> la= resultat.getResultList();  
      Gson gson=new Gson();
      String json =gson.toJson(La);//convert the List to json

      try {
        out.println(json);//return respons to ajax
       } finally {            
        out.close();
       }
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with tomcat IMO.  How are you saving the data? show code.  It has to do with the database sessions and persisting the data. Are you using @Entity or @Cacheable?

Comment: yes im using Entity ...(question updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using  `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"`

You always want to use only one EntityManager.  Have a parent class that manages the same instance of EntityManager across your application.

> It is almost never a good idea to have more than one instance of an
>   EntityManager in use (don't create a second one unless you've
>   destroyed the first)

I think the problem is by creating a new EM here

```
EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
```

Personally, I prefer to use the transaction type, transaction-type="TRANSACTION", to not worry about the entity manager https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963012/643500

You can read more here  http://openejb.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html

When you save the data do you use saveOrUpdate or merge?

This might not be the right answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: hmm, i see what is the problem, when i reloaded the page my app get the data from cache instead from Database... now im looking for flushing cache....

Comment: "When you save the data do you use saveOrUpdate or merge?" for example : person p =new person(..);  /*begin transaction*/ em.persist(p); /*commit transaction*/

Comment: solved , thanks for support the problem is that I change the data of the database since H2 Database consol, rather than from the code(using merge)... :-)