# @Transactional guice annotation using JTA

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, jta, transactional

We have an application running both in Weblogic and Tomcat. We use @Transactional annotation of Guice package to correctly perform the database operations using a persistenceUnit of RESOURCE_LOCAL type using Tomcat.

Using Weblogic, persistence type is JTA, and we get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
```

We are not calling em.getTransaction(), so maybe @Transactional annotation is causing this error?

Regards.

Comment: this link might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962525/persistence-unit-as-resource-local-or-jta

Comment: What does your code look like where the error occurs?

Comment: Finally we changed the type of the persistenceUnit to JTA and it worked. Thanks for the comments.