# What Transaction Manager (JTA) should I use to learn Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta

I am learning Hibernate from the latest 2016 edition (2nd) of the Java Persistence with Hibernate book.  It appears I need a JTA Transaction Manager (TM), but I do not want to have to learn Spring at this point (as suggested in answers to other questions on this) because I perceive it as yet another huge set of infrastructure to learn with its own recursively huge tree of further topics to learn.

Is there a simple TM alternative I can use, or some other path I should be taking?  Perhaps my perception of Spring is wrong and its TM is independent of its other pieces?

Comment: Not sure why asking for help here results in me getting negative votes?

Comment: you don't have to learn spring in order to use JTA as transaction manager in hibernate

Comment: JTA (the [Java Transaction API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API)) does not have anything to do with Spring, you don't need Spring to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this answer, maybe you should what you are looking for.

[Persistence unit as RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962525/persistence-unit-as-resource-local-or-jta)

Comment: This answer, combined with an example [shown here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions) helped answer this thanks.