# EntityManager Throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, weld

I am running the [keycloak Photoz example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/3.1.0.Final/examples/authz/photoz).  When I deploy to Wildfly, the EntityManager is not injected and I get a NullPointerException (below).  I've tried a few different strategies -- tweaking persistence.xml (remove `LOCAL_RESOURCE`) and switching to the `@PersistenceContext` attribute without luck.  Since the examples are canned, one would think I can't be too far off??  I don't really understand Java well enough to debug this. This would seem to have something to do with my Wildfly installation?  But the example is designed to run in wildfly (`mvn clean package wildfly:deploy`). Any advice?

Note:  I am able to manually create the EntityManager as shown below.  Also note, that I must call init(), so something seems to be wrong with DI in this app in general...

```
Resources r = new Resources();
r.init();
EntityManager entityManager = r.createEntityManager();
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
keycloak_1    |     at org.keycloak.example.photoz.album.AlbumService.findAll(AlbumService.java:86)
keycloak_1    |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
keycloak_1    |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
keycloak_1    |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
keycloak_1    |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
keycloak_1    |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
keycloak_1    |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
keycloak_1    |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
keycloak_1    |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
keycloak_1    |     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
```

**Service:**

```
...
@Path("/album")
@Transaction
public class AlbumService {

    public static final String SCOPE_ALBUM_VIEW = "urn:photoz.com:scopes:album:view";
    public static final String SCOPE_ALBUM_DELETE = "urn:photoz.com:scopes:album:delete";

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findAll() {
        return Response.ok(this.entityManager.createQuery("from Album where userId = '" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "'").getResultList()).build();
    }

...
```

**.../src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.keycloak.example.photoz.util.TransactionInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

**.../src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>org.keycloak.example.photoz.entity.Album</class>
        <class>org.keycloak.example.photoz.entity.Photo</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/keycloak-photoz-example" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**.../src/main/java/org/keycloak/example/photoz/util/TransactionInterceptor.java**

```
@Interceptor
@Transaction
public class TransactionInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private Instance<EntityManager> entityManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext context) {
        EntityManager entityManager = this.entityManager.get();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        try {
            transaction.begin();
            Object proceed = context.proceed();
            transaction.commit();
            return proceed;
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(cause);
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**.../src/main/java/org/keycloak/example/photoz/util/Resources.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Resources {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("primary");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void dispose() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your AlbumService a bean? Cause I don't see a bean annotation

Comment: @DavidMaes I'm embarrassed to say I don't know how to answer that question. :(

Comment: Ok so to use the "@Inject", your AlbumService needs to be a Spring Bean I assume in this case? So place the annotation "@Named" above the AlbumService class. Otherwise the injection of the entityManager won't work. Are you using Spring?

Comment: @DavidMaes I added the TransactionInterceptor above.  I suspect this is part of the story as well.  Note that the complete source is available in the Github link in the first para.  

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/3.1.0.Final/examples/authz/photoz

Comment: The interceptor hooks into the jboss application server. So for every transaction it will first go to keycloak to check if the user is logged in I assume. Inside the TransactionInterceptor the entitymanager is wired correctly because the TransactionInterceptor is bean. However the exception states a nullPointer is thrown in the AlbumService which I assume is not a bean as I can't see any configuration that specifies that should be a bean.

Comment: Adding the @Named attribute above AlbumService did not resolve the problem.

Comment: See the "note" above.  If I add the following code to the service call, I can force creation of the EntityManager:

    `Resources r = new Resources();`
    `r.init();`
    `EntityManager entityManager = r.createEntityManager();`

Comment: Ok if that works for you. But looking inside the repository I would think everything should work out of the box. Honestly I can't figure out how the EntityManager should be injected in the AlbumService. And I assume that even if you create the entityManager manually in the AlbumService. You will run into the same problems in the other services?

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that awful workaround as a strategy!  Just in the interest of not sitting on my thumbs -- potentially offering modestly helpful info...    :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that I can help you :/. It might be preferable to contact a developer through the github page.

Comment: No worries.  Appreciate the effort!

Comment: I don't know this example, but a few things I noticed that look strange: a) no Password for your h2 Connection, try 'sa' b) @ Transaction? shouldn't it be @ Transactional in JEE? c) shouldn't it be @ PersistenceContest to inject the EntityManager? d) I think the code in this example is pretty strange, you shouldn't start JEE with writing a Transaction Interceptor!

Comment: Question: you copy the `RESOURCE_LOCAL` example from _keycloak_ but as you are running on Wildfly, can you consider switching to [`JTA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28998110/4906586)? And agreed on @EasterBunnyBugSmasher a): password is missing and I'm also not a fan of Transaction Interceptor neither

Comment: thats because you trying to recreate the EntityManagerFactory which already created in Init. Just change your createEntityManager methode to simple getEntityManager.